# PHP check value in array match conditions then echo out that specific values

Tags: php, arrays, xml, match, sentence

I'm trying to display movie information from the XML list that matches post title.

`$movie_title` is the variable of the movie name.

Now I have 2 problems:

- If title doesn't match then else statement will echo out "No match!" for each move that doesn't match condition of the if statement.
- How to limit result only on the first movie that match the title.

I'm also wondering if there is some better way to do this.

```
$movie_title = get_the_title();
$movies = simplexml_load_file('http://www.kolosej.si/spored/xml/2.0/');

foreach($movies as $movie) {

    $movie_list = $title=$movie->title;

    if((strpos($movie_list, $movie_title)) !== false) {

        echo $original_title=$movie->original_title . '<br>';
        echo $description=$movie->plot_outline;

    } else {
        echo 'No match!';
    }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `foreach` try `in_array()`

Comment: `if(in_array($movie_title ,$movies)){//success code }else{ echo "No Match";}`

Comment: @Manjeet Barnala could you please make an working example? I got errors.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This would work, by setting a `$found` when you actually find a matching movie title and only outputting a `No Match` if the `$found` is not set

```
<?php
$movie_title = get_the_title();
$movies = simplexml_load_file('http://www.kolosej.si/spored/xml/2.0/');
$found = false;

foreach($movies as $movie) {

    $movie_list = $title=$movie->title;

    if((strpos($movie_list, $movie_title)) !== false) {

        echo $original_title=$movie->original_title . '<br>';
        echo $description=$movie->plot_outline;
        $found = true;
        break;  // assuming there will only be one, else leave this out
    }

}
if ( ! $found ) {
    echo 'No match!';
}
```

Comment: Great, it's working! Thank you for your time @RiggsFolly

Comment: My pleasure old chap

Answer (score 0):

replace your code with the following code

```
<?php 
$movie_title = get_the_title();
$movies = simplexml_load_file('http://www.kolosej.si/spored/xml/2.0/');
$array_m =  (array) $movies ;

if(in_array($movie_title,array_column($array_m,'title'))) 
{
    echo $original_title=$movie->original_title . '<br>';
    echo $description=$movie->plot_outline;

} 
else 
{
    echo 'No match!';
}
?>
```

Comment: Does not find anything

Comment: This doesn't work, could you please fix this. It would be great to see how in_array is working.

Comment: Sorry there is no error but It always echo out "No match!" @Manjeet Barnala

Answer (score 0):

You could use `in_array()` as suggested in the comments, or alter your code slightly, so that you cancel the loop, when you found a match, or when the loop finished without finding one, you display "No match"

**Be careful**: `in_array()` does not check for substings, like you want, but only for whole movie titles.

```
 $movie_title = get_the_title();
 $movies = simplexml_load_file('http://www.kolosej.si/spored/xml/2.0/');

foreach($movies as $movie) {

  $movie_list = $title=$movie->title;

  if((strpos($movie_list, $movie_title)) !== false) {
    echo $original_title=$movie->original_title . '<br>';
    echo $description=$movie->plot_outline;
    $found = true;
    break;
  }
}
if(!$found)
  echo "Not found!";
```

Comment: Thank you @chillichief I really like your idea!